# Is it possbile to deploy an Android standalone wear app to galaxy store?

Tags: tizen, samsung-galaxy, android-wear-2.0

I have an existing Android Wear standalone app and I would like that my app works on Samsung Galaxy watches. Is is possible to deploy the app on Galaxy store or do I have to make the whole app from scratch using Tizen Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware Samsung has created an [application compatibility layer](https://www.tizenhelp.com/developers-released-new-update-for-acl-for-tizen/) which mentions support on both Samsung mobile and watch devices.
That promises Android application execution on tizen 'without any changes to the source application'

But IMHO I'd be quite shocked if this works well enough, if at all on watches.
There is just too much work to ensure compatibility with round screens let alone everything else. But I've never tried it and would be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) What about making the wear app using react native and deploy it to galaxy store, is that an opportunity?

Comment: Curious to know if there is this kind of non volatile memory available for more complex data?

Comment: Was searching and found this article, so maybe it is possible to make it using react 

https://github.com/rovale/react-tizen-watch

Answer (score 0):

ACL (Application Compatibility Air) for Tizen mentioned in https://www.tizenhelp.com/developers-released-new-update-for-acl-for-tizen/ is not supported for Wearable devices.

Comment: @Lunch Basketball Directly from your link (which had already been provided in the other answer) it states "The ACL for Tizen app is must have app for Tizen smartphones and smartwatches.". Not that it can't be bad information but exactly on what authority or reference do you say otherwise?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was pre-built apps. I found another page for this tools. Support only Mobile devices.. I think.. Wearable can't be supported by limited resources (ram, cpu, storage, etc)... https://nr001store.blogspot.com/2019/04/acl-for-tizen-download-acl-for-tizen.html